# How to limit query size written to slow log?

Tags: mysql

My slow logs are filled with huge insert/update queries (between 100+ kbyte per query). How do I get MySQL to not write the entire query to the log?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use logrotate on it. For a quick fix you can do this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html

Comment: I don't want to limit total file size, I want to limit size of each query logged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  --log-short-format then mysql will use shorter format.

Comment: What exactly is the shorter log format?

Comment: "Log less information to the binary log and slow query log." this from mysql site... never use it so can't give you any example but you can try. Also check if you maybe have enabled log-long-format this options logs much more info